# How do I show multiple custom annotations (pin & left icon) loaded via plist?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

will this code when working show custom pins and logos or just 1 pin with custom logos? please see plist below, only error is Local declaration of mapView hides instance variable.

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>stationIdKey</key>
    <string>BP</string>
    <key>stationNameKey</key>
    <string>Atkinson Dam Cabin Village</string>
    <key>stationAddressKey</key>
    <string>Atkinson Dam Road, Atkinson Dam</string>
    <key>stationLatitudeKey</key>
    <string>-27.415056</string>
    <key>stationLongitudeKey</key>
    <string>152.43057</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>stationIdKey</key>
    <string>Shell</string>
    <key>stationNameKey</key>
    <string>BP - AYR DCA</string>
    <key>stationAddressKey</key>
    <string>108 Edwards Street, AYR</string>
    <key>stationLatitudeKey</key>
    <string>-19.57094107</string>
    <key>stationLongitudeKey</key>
    <string>147.4025662</string>
</dict>
```

and the mapViewController.m file

```
- (void)viewDidload
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stations" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *anns = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"anns=%@",anns);

for(NSMutableDictionary *note in anns) {
    float realLatitude = [[note objectForKey:@"stationLatitudeKey"] floatValue];
    float realLongitude = [[note objectForKey:@"stationLongitudeKey"] floatValue];        
    MyAnnotation* myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
    theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;
    myAnnotation.coordinate = theCoordinate;
    myAnnotation.title = [note objectForKey:@"stationNameKey"];
    myAnnotation.subtitle = [note objectForKey:@"stationAddressKey"];
    myAnnotation.stationIdKey = [note objectForKey:@"stationIdKey"];
    [mapView setDelegate:self];
    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
    [myAnnotation release];        
} }



-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{  if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
{
    static NSString *reuseId = @"customAnn";

    MKAnnotationView *customAnnotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (customAnnotationView == nil)
    {
        customAnnotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId] autorelease];
        UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin-green.png"];
        [customAnnotationView setImage:pinImage];
        customAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        customAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    }

    NSString *iconFilename = @"";
    MyAnnotation *myAnn = (MyAnnotation *)annotation;
    if ([myAnn.stationIdKey isEqualToString:@"BP"])
        iconFilename = @"bp-logo.png";
    else
        if ([myAnn.stationIdKey isEqualToString:@"Caltex"])
            iconFilename = @"caltex.png";
        else
            if ([myAnn.stationIdKey isEqualToString:@"Shell"])
                iconFilename = @"shell.png";
    UIImageView *leftIconView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:iconFilename]] autorelease];
    customAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftIconView;

    customAnnotationView.annotation = annotation;

    return customAnnotationView; 
}

return nil; }


-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{ if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
{
    MyAnnotation *myAnn = (MyAnnotation *)view.annotation;
    NSLog(@"callout button tapped for station id %@", myAnn.stationIdKey);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"callout button tapped for annotation %@", view.annotation);
} }
```

Comment: I've updated the answer based on the new code and warning message.

Comment: After the arrayWithContentsOfFile line, put `NSLog(@"anns=%@",anns);`.  What does it say?  Don't worry about the "hides instance variable" warning for now.  Also, if you add a comment to the answer when you update the question, I'll get notified.

Comment: Thanks Anna this is all i get: GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Aug  8 20:32:45 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 1196.

Comment: Did you change the plist file?  Does the arrayWithContentsOfFile line execute?  Put a breakpoint on it.  Does the debugger stop there?

Comment: Thanks Anna hope I'm not frustrating you i have added current plist above (haven't changed), also when i add breakpoint where suggested i get - Pending breakpoint 1 - ""MapViewController.m":97" resolved – sorry added it properly this time...

Comment: Hi Anna I have changed my question slightly but I am very happy for the map to show only different icons for the same pins if I can get that to work, am I able to send my whole project to you somehow?

Comment: The NSLog I suggested above should have printed a line in the console like "anns=<12345>" or "anns=(null)".  Please test that again.  After the debugger stops at the arrayWithContentsOfFile line, step through the code in viewDidLoad one line at a time.  Does it enter the for-loop?  Are the dicts in the plist contained in an <array> tag which is in a <plist> tag, etc?  The code was working before (right?) and, in my test, the changes I show in the answer work when applied to your original code and plist.

Comment: (Not frustrated by the way, don't worry.)

Comment: Hi Anna the log only shows Pending breakpoint 1 - ""MapViewController.m":(whatever line)" resolved.

Comment: i have added all files again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Posting a separate answer for the slightly modified question.  The original question was how to change the annotation callout image based on some property of the annotation object.  The modified question is why the annotations are not appearing at all based on the latest code and how to fix the warning in viewForAnnotation.)*

The only obvious problem with the latest code in the question is that the `viewDidLoad` method is spelled wrong which prevents that code from getting called at all.  Please change this:

```
- (void)viewDidload  //the lowercase "l" is not correct, must be uppercase
```

to this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

A few other things to check just in case:

- Plist file should really be like `<?xml ...><!DOCTYPE ...><plist ...><array><dict>xxx</dict><dict>yyy</dict><dict>zzz</dict></array></plist>`
- Make sure the image files like `pin-green.png`, etc have been added to the project and are named *exactly* that way (uppercase/lowercase matters on the device)

Next, to fix the compiler warning in `viewForAnnotation`, change the name of the `mapView` parameter to something else so it's different from the `mapView` ivar in the view controller.  Following example changes it to `aMapView` (two places marked with `^^^^^^`):

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
                                          ^^^^^^^^
{  
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
    {
        static NSString *reuseId = @"customAnn";

        MKAnnotationView *customAnnotationView = [aMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
                                                  ^^^^^^^^
        if (customAnnotationView == nil)
        {
            customAnnotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId] autorelease];
            UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin-green.png"];
            [customAnnotationView setImage:pinImage];
            customAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
            UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            customAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        }

        NSString *iconFilename = @"";
        MyAnnotation *myAnn = (MyAnnotation *)annotation;
        if ([myAnn.stationIdKey isEqualToString:@"BP"])
            iconFilename = @"bp-logo.png";
        else
            if ([myAnn.stationIdKey isEqualToString:@"Caltex"])
                iconFilename = @"caltex.png";
            else
                if ([myAnn.stationIdKey isEqualToString:@"Shell"])
                    iconFilename = @"shell.png";
        UIImageView *leftIconView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:iconFilename]] autorelease];
        customAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftIconView;

        customAnnotationView.annotation = annotation;

        return customAnnotationView; 
    }

    return nil; 
}
```

This is how it looks (your pin and callout images may be different):

[image: Green Pins]

[image: Shell Callout]

[image: Caltex Callout]

[image: BP Callout]

If you want the pins themselves to have different images instead of their callouts, then in `viewForAnnotation`, call `setImage` instead of setting the `leftCalloutAccessoryView`.

Another minor, unrelated, thing is that you don't need to call `mapView setDelegate` inside the for-loop.  You only need to call it once before the for-loop (and if you've already connected the map view's delegate to File's Owner in the xib, you don't need to do it in code at all).

Comment: Thanks Anna works brilliant!! was the "L" all along... is it possible to have different pins aswell as logo's?

Comment: Do you mean a different image for each pin instead of all pin-green.png?  As mentioned below the BP callout image, in viewForAnnotation, where it is currently setting customAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView, you can instead (or also) set customAnnotationView.image.  _Example:_ `customAnnotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:iconFilename];`

Comment: Thanks Anna that works great but i have a different pin image for each station as well as a different left icon image (2x different images each type) how would i go about setting this???

Comment: You can set both as mentioned in my last comment.  It's the same principle.  Write some if-condition in the viewForAnnotation method based on properties of the annotation and set the view's properties.  The code in the answer is just an example and one way to do it.  Try  changing the code according to what you need and start a new question if any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `stationIdKey` property to your custom annotation class `MyAnnotation` and set the property when creating the annotation before calling `addAnnotation`.  For example:

```
//in MyAnnotation.h:
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *stationIdKey; //and release in dealloc

//in viewDidLoad before calling addAnnotation:
myAnnotation.stationIdKey = [note objectForKey:@"stationIdKey"];
```

Then in `viewForAnnotation`, cast `annotation` to the custom class and set the icon based on the `stationIdKey` property:

```
NSString *iconFilename = @"";
MyAnnotation *myAnn = (MyAnnotation *)annotation;
if ([myAnn.stationIdKey isEqualToString:@"BP"])
    iconFilename = @"bp-logo.png";
else
    if ([myAnn.stationIdKey isEqualToString:@"Caltex"])
        iconFilename = @"caltex.png";
    else
        if ([myAnn.stationIdKey isEqualToString:@"Shell"])
            iconFilename = @"shell.png";
UIImageView *leftIconView = [[[UIImageView alloc] 
    initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:iconFilename]] autorelease];
```

*(There are a few other issues with the code which I'll add details about later.)*

---

**Edit:**
Sorry, I wasn't clear that the code shown above for `viewForAnnotation` is only supposed to replace the part of the existing code that sets the `leftCalloutAccessoryView`.  It's not the whole delegate method.

The warning `Control reaches end of non-void function` means that the replacement code is not returning a value even though the method is declared as returning a `MKAnnotationView *`.

Below is the full method with other unrelated suggested changes:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
    {
        static NSString *reuseId = @"customAnn";

        MKAnnotationView *customAnnotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
        if (customAnnotationView == nil)
        {
            customAnnotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId] autorelease];
            UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin-green.png"];
            [customAnnotationView setImage:pinImage];
            customAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
            UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            customAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        }

        NSString *iconFilename = @"";
        MyAnnotation *myAnn = (MyAnnotation *)annotation;
        if ([myAnn.stationIdKey isEqualToString:@"BP"])
            iconFilename = @"bp-logo.png";
        else
            if ([myAnn.stationIdKey isEqualToString:@"Caltex"])
                iconFilename = @"caltex.png";
            else
                if ([myAnn.stationIdKey isEqualToString:@"Shell"])
                    iconFilename = @"shell.png";
        UIImageView *leftIconView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:iconFilename]] autorelease];
        customAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftIconView;

        customAnnotationView.annotation = annotation;

        return customAnnotationView; 
    }

    return nil;
}
```

I've added the following:

- Only create a custom annotation view if the annotation type is `MyAnnotation` otherwise return `nil`.  So if you decide later to show other types of annotations like user location, it will still work.
- Implemented annotation view re-use by calling the dequeue method.  This can improve performance if you have a lot of annotations.
- Moved the setting of annotation view properties that don't change per annotation to only when the view is newly created (and not being re-used).
- Removed the `addTarget:action:` call for the `rightButton`.  I highly recommend you implement the map view's `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method instead of a custom method.  So instead of an `annotationViewClick:` method, implement the delegate method, like this:

  ```
  -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
  {
      if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
      {
          MyAnnotation *myAnn = (MyAnnotation *)view.annotation;
          NSLog(@"callout button tapped for station id %@", myAnn.stationIdKey);
      }
      else
      {
          NSLog(@"callout button tapped for annotation %@", view.annotation);
      }
  }
  ```

Finally, in `viewDidLoad`, you are creating the `anns` array using `alloc` but you are not calling `release` which results in a memory leak.

Either replace the alloc+init of the `anns` array with this auto-release version (recommended):

```
NSArray *anns = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

or add this after the for-loop right before the end of the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[anns release];
```

Comment: Thanks Anna your response is greatly appreciated, I just have an issue with a warning displaying when I add the } to the end of my viewForAnnotation (which I am sure has to be present or the rest of my code fails, also when I run the app it crashes at the point of showing the annotations, what's your thoughts? Can i send you my full app via email?

Comment: Can you please edit the Question and add the updated code?  You can shorten the plist sample to one annotation.  Also give the exact warning you get and on what line.  Also give the exact message you get when it crashes and stack trace if possible.

Comment: Anna, sorry this is the only way i can get help, my app loads approximately 5000 annotations from the plist which takes approx 20 secs... is there any way of speeding this up by loading only the annotations within say 20km of user location?

Comment: See my comment on the question you created for this.