# Several and different custom Pins in the same mapView

Tags: mkmapview, mkannotationview, mapkit

This is my question....

I have a mapView and i fill the view with several custom pins.
I would different custom pins in my mapView.

I have tried with an IF condition but don't work.
I don't understand how the called to method works.

Follow the code.
Vi allego il codice.

```
//Customization of my pins
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    static NSString *identifier = @"";

    MKAnnotationView *pin = [ mappa dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier ];        

//OLD COORDINATES
    if(newcoordinate == FALSE){

        pin = [[[ MKAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier ]autorelease];
        pin.image = [ UIImage imageNamed:@"old.png" ]       
 } 

// NEW COORDINATES
    else ( newcoordinate == TRUE){
        pin = [[[ MKAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier ]autorelease];
        pin.image = [ UIImage imageNamed:@"new.png" ];
} 

    pin.canShowCallout = YES;

//CALLOUT INFO
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"informations.png"];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]autorelease];
    pin.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imgView;

pin.annotation = annotation;

return pin;}
```

The result is... several pin in the same mapView but with the same customization.
:/

Thank you.

Comment: What is `newCoordinate`?  Show how the "old' and "new" annotations are added.  See the two answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325200/how-do-i-show-multiple-custom-annotations-pin-left-icon-loaded-via-plist/8402031#8402031) for code examples that may help you.  BTW, the line `else ( newcoordinate == TRUE){` should be `else if ( newcoordinate == TRUE){` but that won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED.**
I have added a new property in MyAnnotation class:

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    BOOL isNew;  // <------- My solution    
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isNew ; <--------- My solution
```

Today i have learned what are the properties.