# MKPinAnnotationView loses pinColor after MKMapView zoom in

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have a MKMapView with a lot of annotation pins defined from a parser xml; thats my code:

```
-(IBAction)LoadAnnotation:(id)sender {

    RXML element ...
    RXML iterate....

    [myMap removeAnnotations:myMap.annotations];
    annotation.title = // NSString from RXML parser
    annotation.subtitle = // NSString from RXML parser
    myValue = // float value from RXML parser
    [mymap addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

and then

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation2 {

       MKPinAnnotationView *pinView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation2 reuseIdentifier:@"MyPin"];

        if ( myValue > 0 && myValue < 10) {
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
            pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
            return pinView;
        }

        else if ( myValue > 10 && myValue < 20 ) {
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
        return pinView;
    }

        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
        return pinView;
}
```

All right, when my MKMapView is loaded, I can see title annotations, subtitle annotations and all the pins with different colours.

But if I scroll and zoom IN the map at a certain level, then zoom OUT again, all the pins become PURPLE.  What's happening there?

I have tried also using same "annotation" (id) in the two methods (and not "annotation" and "annotation2"), but I have no result.

Is there a way to avoid that and keep pinColors after map scroll and zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewForAnnotation` delegate method isn't necessarily called only once for each annotation nor is it guaranteed to be called in the order that you add the annotations.  It's also called for the user location (blue dot) if you set `showsUserLocation` to `YES`.

When you zoom or pan the map, the map view will call the delegate method (again) as annotations come back into view.  At that time, your `myValue` will have no relevance to the annotation the map is requesting a view for.

Instead of using a class-level ivar, **add `myValue` as a property of your annotation class** and set it along with the `title` and `subtitle` before you call `addAnnotation`:

```
annotation.title = // NSString from RXML parser
annotation.subtitle = // NSString from RXML parser
annotation.myValue = // float value from RXML parser
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then in `viewForAnnotation`, use the `myValue` property from the `annotation` parameter instead of an ivar.  This way, the delegate method is always using information specific to the annotation  it is requesting a view for:

```
if ( ! [annotation isKindOfClass:[MyCustomAnnotationClass class]])
{
    return nil;  //return a default view if not your custom class
}

//cast annotation to custom class so we can get the custom property...
MyCustomAnnotationClass *myPin = (MyCustomAnnotationClass *)annotation;

//use the custom property in the annotation instead of ivar...
if (myPin.myValue > 0 && myPin.myValue < 10) {
    ....
```

Changing the name of the `annotation` parameter to `annotation2` is not necessary.

Unrelated but you should be implementing annotation view re-use by using `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` (search for it in the SDK or on SO).  It can help with performance if there are a lot of annotations.

---

Your `MyAnnotation` class should look like this:

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    float myValue;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate; //<-- add
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;                     //<-- add
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;                  //<-- add
@property (nonatomic, assign) float myValue;
@end

@implementation MyAnnotation
@synthesize coordinate; //<-- add
@synthesize title;      //<-- add
@synthesize subtitle;   //<-- add
@synthesize myValue;
@end
```

The place where you add the annotation should look like this:

```
MyAnnotation *annotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.title = someTitle;       // NSString from RXML parser
annotation.subtitle = someSubTitle; // NSString from RXML parser
annotation.myValue = someValue;     // someValue from RXML parser
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Above, `someValue` is whatever `myValue` was in your original `ViewController`.

Also, in `viewForAnnotation`, change `annotation2` back to `annotation` and don't forget to put `MKPinAnnotationView *pinView =[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] init...` before the `MyAnnotation *myPin = ...` line.

Comment: Thank u very much Anna Karenina, great explanation! I have understood but Unluckly I have some difficulty to write the code, because I have the annotations method just in the ViewController class. So I have tried to declare in ViewController.h a property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *myValue; and in ViewController.m syntesize myValue; then I have added your code to viewForAnnotation method, changing in the specific ViewController *myPin = (ViewController *)annotation and I have no errors but all the pin now are RED; can U be more specific with the code please??

Comment: You have to add the property to annotation class (not the view controller).  In LoadAnnotation, how do you alloc+init the `annotation` variable?

Comment: In a ViewController -(IBAction) I have annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; where annotation is a MKPointAnnotation *annotation; declared in interface

Comment: Instead of using the built-in MKPointAnnotation class, you'll have to create a custom annotation class that implements MKAnnotation.  See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8463420/467105) which names the custom class "MyAnnotation".  If you decide to use the same name, then in the current answer, replace "MyCustomAnnotationClass" with "MyAnnotation".  Right now, you might have replaced it with ViewController which is incorrect.

Comment: Perfect Anna Karenina! Thank u very much, this is the answer. Only a little trouble: in viewForAnnotation method I need to "return [pinView autorelease]" every my "if" and "else" condition, and compiler give me a "potential leak of an object stored into 'pinView'" into your "if ( ! [annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]]) {}". it's normal?

Comment: If you're not using ARC, then yes, you need to do `[pinView autorelease]`.  You'd also need to do `[annotation release];` after the addAnnotation line.  If you still get warnings, you may want to start a new question for it.

Comment: No, Im not using ARC, and yes, I need to "return [pinView autorelease]"... only into your "if ( ! [annotation isKindOfClass:[MyCustomAnnotationClass class]])" the "return nil" give a potential leak on pinView, but I think it doesnt affect the app... thank u again for your accepted answer, you saved my a lot of time!

Comment: It sounds like the `[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] init...` line is before the `if ( !...` part.  The `if ( !...` block should be at the very top _before_ the view is allocated.

Comment: Perfect, if block must be at top. Anna Karenina, you are the (wo)man! ;=) If u have time, can u take a look to my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834744/mkuserlocation-showed-on-simulator-and-not-on-real-device ? Thanks!