# MKPointAnnotation subtitle

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation

I have created many pins, and when I press on the pin the title must show, while the subtitle must be hidden, because it is a long piece of text and it appears in a UItextView. The problem is that I didn't find a way to hide the subtitle, so under the title, I have a long piece of text which ends with: ...

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    MKPointAnnotation *myAnnot = (MKPointAnnotation *)view.annotation;
    field.text = myAnnot.subtitle;
}
```

Unfortunately I had to use this method because I can't find a way to assign a tag to the MKPointAnnotation. This is how I create it:

```
MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotationPoint2.coordinate = anyLocation;

annotationPoint2.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", obj];
annotationPoint2.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the built-in `MKPointAnnotation` class, create a custom annotation class that implements `MKAnnotation` but with an additional property (not named `subtitle`) to hold the data you don't want to show on the callout.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804781/mkpinannotationview-loses-pincolor-after-mkmapview-zoom-in/12805161#12805161) contains an example of a simple, custom annotation class.

In that example, replace `@property (nonatomic, assign) float myValue;` with the data you want to track with each annotation (eg. `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *keyValue;`).

Then you would create your annotations like this:

```
MyAnnotation *annotationPoint2 = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
annotationPoint2.coordinate = anyLocation;

annotationPoint2.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", obj];
annotationPoint2.subtitle = @"";  //or set to nil
annotationPoint2.keyValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
```

Then the `didSelectAnnotationView` method would look like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
    {
        MyAnnotation *myAnnot = (MyAnnotation *)view.annotation;
        field.text = myAnnot.keyValue;
    }
    else
    {
        //handle other types of annotations (eg. MKUserLocation)...
    }
}
```

You may also have to update other parts of your code that assume the annotation is a `MKPointAnnotation` or that uses the annotation's `subtitle` (that code should check for `MyAnnotation` and use `keyValue`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this easy way,

```
MKPointAnnotation *point= [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point.coordinate= userLocation.coordinate;
point.title= @"Where am I?";
point.subtitle= @"u&me here!!!";
[myMapView addAnnotation:point];
```